# Enable/disable Lockscreen Widgets since Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-widget, android-4.2-jelly-bean, lockscreen

I am trying to add custom widget on [Lockscreen](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Lockscreen) (Android 4.2 and above).

I understand I have to add attribute android:widgetCategory to widget XML file. But what I don´t understand, how to enable/disable it.

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

I thought I just enable it and after device is lock, it will appear there and when I disable it, it will not appear after device is lock.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The user will add your widget to the lock screen if they want it.

You are only enabling the ability for them to do this. You are not adding the widget to the home screen for the user.